# # appearing in URL for UI.Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I had an issue a few days ago where I would get a random # inside the URL like:

```
http://localhost:55462/#/forgotpassword
```

I asked a question about this and added this inside my app.config section:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
});
```

Thiss did not remove the # sign but just move it and now the URL looks like this:

```
http://localhost:55462/#forgotpassword
```

My current routing looks like:

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
$stateProvider
    .state('login', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
        controller: 'loginController'
    })
    .state('forgotpassword', {
        url: '/forgotpassword',
        templateUrl: 'partials/forgotpassword.html',
        controller: 'forgotPasswordController'
    })
    .state('forgotpasswordcode', {
        url: '/forgotpasswordcode',
        templateUrl: 'partials/forgotpasswordcode.html',
        controller: 'forgotPasswordController'
    })
    .state('forgotpasswordnewpassword', {
        url: '/forgotpasswordnewpassword',
        templateUrl: 'partials/forgotpasswordnewpassword.html',
        controller: 'forgotPasswordController'
    })
    .state('dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard.html',
        controller: 'calenderController'
    })
    .state('dashboard.calender', {
        url: '/calender',
        templateUrl: 'partials/dashboard.calender.html',
        controller: 'calenderController'
    })

$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
});

//.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login', controller: 'loginController' })
```

});

and when i am redirecting to another page i am using:

```
$location.path('/forgotpasswordcode');
```

Can anyone help me out with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$state.go()` instead of `$location.path()`. Make sure to inject `$state` wherever you want to use it also

```
$state.go(stateName[,params]) // example $state.go('dashboard.calender')
```

`$state` is a service provided by ui-router